# where does the perforce plugin for hudson stores the label of a tagged build?

Tags: hudson, label, perforce

I want to know the location or path of the label( tag name ) is stored after a particular build is tagged with the label.

Answer (score 1):

It is stored in the build.xml of the build in question. So for build number 44 of "JOB1", it would be in $HUDSON_HOME/jobs/JOB1/builds/44/build.xml. The xpath in the build.xml to the value is /build/actions/hudson.plugins.perforce.PerforceTagAction/tag.

Note that this is just the label name. The label itself is still stored in perforce.